# sudzc 101 (response issue)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, soap, sudzc

I'm sure this will be very simple for you experts. SUDZC is set up and everything seems to work properly but when a value is returned to the delegate, it is null.  the NSLog shows the correct XML response, so i know that it is working properly, but the value in the code is showing null. SUDZC comes with a sample program and this is how it runs.  i created a test function on the web service "WhatsYourFavoriteMovie" which returns "Pulp Fiction". The logging clearly shows this value being returned.  Why is the final value (null)?? Please help, thank you.

so i call...

```
[service WhatsYourFavoriteMovie:self action:@selector(WhatsYourFavoriteMovieHandler:) userid: 1];
```

and then when the web service responds it goes to...

```
// Handle the response from WhatsYourFavoriteMovie.
- (void) WhatsYourFavoriteMovieHandler: (id) value {

// Handle errors
if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
NSLog(@"%@", value);
return;
}

// Handle faults
if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
NSLog(@"%@", value);
return;
}


// Do something with the NSString* result
NSString* result = (NSString*)value;
NSLog(@"WhatsYourFavoriteMovie returned the value: %@", result);
}
```

however "value" and "result" are always 'null'... as you can see in the NSLog output below it is returning "Pulp Fiction" in the  tag.  Where am i going wrong?

```
2012-02-17 17:27:41.487 SudzCExamples[2782:f803] Loading:     https://www.mydomain.com/tk_services/tk.asmx

2012-02-17 17:27:41.491 SudzCExamples[2782:f803] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     
xmlns="com.mynamespace"><soap:Body><WhatsYourFavoriteMovie>
<userid>1</userid></WhatsYourFavoriteMovie></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

2012-02-17 17:27:41.497 SudzCExamples[2782:f803]
Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

2012-02-17 17:27:45.947 SudzCExamples[2782:f803]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body>
<WhatsYourFavoriteMovieResponse xmlns="com.mynamespace">
<WhatsYourFavoriteMovieResult>Pulp Fiction</WhatsYourFavoriteMovieResult>
</WhatsYourFavoriteMovieResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

2012-02-17 17:27:45.949 SudzCExamples[2782:f803] WhatsYourFavoriteMovie returned the value: (null)"
```

once again, as you can see in the log it got the value "pulp fiction" from the server, but the final line of the log says it returned value 'null'. please help me!! thank you.

Comment: Check out Phil Hale's answer, I ran into the same problem and it works for me. If it solves your problem remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem with the ARC version of the Sudzc generated code, but for whatever reason the non-ARC version worked fine

UPDATE

Check out this [issue report](http://code.google.com/p/sudzc/issues/detail?id=40). I made the change suggested in the first comment and the ARC version worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do try to NSLog the response in didrecivedata. in the class SoapRequest.m

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)value {

    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"data receives %@",str);

}
```

Then you will come to know what the exact problem is.
Post the response after doing this,we help will you according to that.

Comment: When I add this logging to SoapRequest.m I see the full SOAP envelope in the response. However, my handler (coded according to the Sudzc documentation) returns a value of null. Any ideas?

Comment: my log is the same as the log Kevin added to the original post. The NSLog shows the full, correct SOAP envelope being returned, but the delegate method's value parameter is null.

Comment: Try to search this Following code in the file which Sudz has generated and NSLog its corresponding value                                 **[Soap getNodeValue: node withName: @"WhatsYourFavoriteMovieResult"]**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ARC version, in SoapRequest, change the line

```
CXMLNode* element = [[Soap getNode: [doc rootElement] withName:@"Body"] childAtIndex:0];
```

with

```
CXMLNode* element = [[Soap getNode: [doc rootElement] withName:@"soap:Body"] childAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: This does not work for me and I don't see why it would. "soap" is a namespace prefix - not the name of the element. The non-ARC version of Sudzc works just fine when the code is: `CXMLNode* element = [[Soap getNode: [doc rootElement] withName:@"Body"] childAtIndex:0];` so I don't think that this is the problem.

Comment: ...or at least it's not always the solution to the problem in all cases of the reported symptoms.